# Calendar Crashes While Opening - NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores or NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: calendar, macos

The calendar crashes after 1s while opening. I already opened the temp dir `open $TMPDIR..`deleted the cache `C` folder, restarted the computer and deleted the trash. This was not successful. Even after the upgrade to sierra the calendar is still broken.

I created a guest user account, where I'm able to open the calendar. But I cannot open it on my main (admin) account.

I tried to open the calendar after I had booted from safe mode. I also tried to open the calendar in safe mode, which was also not possible. The error is the same.

### main error

```
This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (unknown).  It cannot perform a save operation.
```

### full error

I trimmed the error a bit otherwise I couldn't post it there.

```
Process:               Calendar [27732]
Path:                  /Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/Calendar
Identifier:            com.apple.iCal
Version:               9.0 (2155)
Build Info:            iCal-2155000000000000~2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Calendar [27732]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-10-10 13:27:38.511 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        DD7A2269-DAE5-C038-6F53-34D6AAA3EF21

Sleep/Wake UUID:       160FAB72-D6A8-4065-90C4-627329158025

Time Awake Since Boot: 250000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       50000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.m-user.com.apple.CalendarAgent.proxy

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00003562149bbec0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]


===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            583.7M      829 

Model: MacBookAir6,2, BootROM MBA61.0099.B22, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1,4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.13f15
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A544D4C41522D4E544D
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.10.1a16)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0f18, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 23.6
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after updating to Sierra.  Saw in some other forums that it was linked to gmail calendar accounts.  Assuming you have a gmail calendar account linked, try disabling the gmail account from Settings and then opening calendar.  Once open you can re-enable the gmail calendar and it works fine (at least for me it does).

Not a solution to the problem, but a temporary fix to allow you to use calendar until Apple figures this out.

Comment: Thx, but I disabled syncing for iCal in Settings->ICloud. But where else can I disable the google calendar ( i cannot open the calendar app)? On my Iphone the calendar works fine but does not show any google calendars.

Comment: I also opened this page: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect and unselected all checkboxes (besides the email, this one I cannot change).

Comment: To add to this answer: I noticed that my Calendar app started crashing after I tried to edit an externally managed (outlook) calendar event from within Calendar. So maybe avoiding doing that will help prevent the problem from happening in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to 10.12 a few days ago, Calendar (and Contacts, Mail, and Messages) wouldn't open for me either, but for another reason:

```
AddressBookSourceSync: Could not get real path for Address Book lock folder: open() for F_GETPATH failed.
AddressBookSourceSync: *** Assertion failure in -[ABProcessSharedLock initWithLockFilePath:localLock:fileServices:], /SourceCache/AddressBook/AddressBook-1563/Framework/AddressBookUI/ABProcessSharedLock.m:57
AddressBookSourceSync: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: lockFilePath != nil'
```

But I fixed it by deleting the files that store Internet Accounts settings and deleting temporary folders, so that might work here too.

**Files that store Internet Accounts settings:**

Removing these files will remove sync settings and synced data from your computer, but as long as your data is synced already, you can just add the accounts back in Internet Accounts later.

- `~/Library/Accounts` (Internet Accounts)
- `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook` (Contacts)
- `~/Library/Calendars` (Calendar)
- `~/Library/Mail` (Mail)

After deleting these folders, log out and log back in.

**Temporary folders:**

Save and close your work before you trash any of these folders.

- `~/Library/Caches`
  (You can trash this entire folder.)
- `/private/tmp`
  (You can trash this entire folder. `/tmp` is a symlink to this folder, don't trash that.)
- `/var/folders`
  (If you trash this entire folder, your system might not start up. You must re-create `/var/folders` and `/var/folders/zz` before you restart. You can do this with: `sudo mkdir -p /var/folders/zz`.)

After deleting these folders, do a hard restart (ctrl-cmd-power or ctrl-cmd-eject).

Answer (score 0):

Not a Fix, but a workaround:

I had this same problem going from Sierra to High Sierra (10.13.2). The Calendar app would start and crash as it was "updating calendars". To test that it was my old data causing the issue I created a folder in ~Library/Calendar and dropped all the contents of ~Library/Calendar into it (essentially hiding all the previous data). I then launched the calendar app and viola, it started just fine, but empty. It did load my CalDev account I have on my Synology. Instead of spending more time fiddling with my old calendar data, I just let it rebuild itself from the Synology. I assume it will do the same if you have a copy of your calendar synced with your own local server or a cloud.

Comment: Thx I reinstalled the whole OS to get rid of this issue